# Customize VS Code color scheme of method calls

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, color-scheme

I am customizing the current default Color theme of VSCode and run into trouble when trying to highlight method calls, i.e., meta.function-call.generic textmate-scopes in my user settings. I can only find examples online which use

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "name": "function-call generic",
          "scope": "meta.function-call.generic",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#FEAA4F"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

which does not seem to work for me. I am using

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark Modern]": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
            "selfParameter": "#afaaaa",
            "parameter":  "#996633",
            "variable": "#ffffffe8",
        },
    }
}
```

at the moment. I thought I could simply add `"meta.function-call.generic": "somehexvalue"` but that does not work either. I have little experience in customizing VS code. I only change settings by point & click, change hotkeys or edit some lines in the debugger launch.json. Aside from an answer, I would appreciate tips on how I might figure out the solution by myself. For example maybe I could use intellisense in some clever way?

Comment: `semanticHighLighting` is different from syntax highlighting, it needs a language server